# loadingRecords conflicts with zeroRecords or emptyTable when dataTable returns empty value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, datatable

I'm facing an issue when I try to load a web page using dataTable with no records found. After investigating, I saw two options when I using in language configuration that somehow conflicts each other when posting a message to the user.

I'm using DataTables 1.10.4 version and cakephp 2.5.4 version.

When dataTable is loading data from a request Ajax, the message setted in loadingRecords shows to the user and saying "Carregando...".

If there are data available to show in dataTable, this message from loadingRecords disappears and all data are available to the final user.

If there are no data available to show in dataTable, the option zeroRecords should take over and shows to the user the message "Nenhum registro encontrado". But the problem is the message "Carregando..." still showing and nothing happen. This is awful if the final user expects some data in the page.

Is there a known issue about zeroRecords message not working? Even if I try to use emptyTable this dataTable won't work.

By the way, after remove loadingRecords option and refresh the browser, the message from zeroRecords works. BUT, if there data to be processed, this message still there and only disappears after loading entire table.

Here following config dataTable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var Server = window.location.hostname;
$("#datatable-4").DataTable({
    //processing: true,
    //serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "http://"+ Server +"/epedidos/Clientes/RequestAllClientes",
        type: 'POST'
    },
    columns: [
        {data: "IdCliente"},
        {data: "Inclusao"},
        {data: "IdERP"},
        {data: "NomeFantasia"},
        {
            data: "CidadeId",
            type: "string"
        },
        {data: "Telefone"}

    ],
    language: {
        search:         "Buscar:",
        loadingRecords: "Carregando...",
        processing:     "Processando...",
        zeroRecords:    "Nenhum registro encontrado",
        emptyTable:     "Não há dados disponíveis na tabela",
        lengthMenu:     "Mostrando _MENU_",
        info:           "Mostrando de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
        infoEmpty:      "Mostrando de 0 a 0 de 0 registros",
        infoFiltered:   "(Filtrado de _MAX_ registros totais)",
        infoPostFix:    "",
        decimal: ",",
        thousands: ".",
        paginate: {
            first:      "Primeiro",
            previous:   "Anterior",
            next:       "Próximo",
            last:       "Último"
        },
    }

});
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw'; 
});
```

Could someone help me with this problem?

If I need clarify something else, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data tables website has stressed too much on incorrect JSON.

There is whole section of what you are looking for on the data tables website:

http://datatables.net/faqs/  (Check the Server-side processing). I know this is not a complete solution that you are looking for.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Anup Kale,
I read this documentation about large number of rows in DataTables using Server-side option.
My DataTables works fine when there are rows returned by Ajax Request.
My problem is: if Ajax Request returns nothing in this same query (ZERO Rows or Null). Why I cannot see a message inform there is no record to show to the end user in this DataTables?

Comment: After reviewing this document again, I found out that I need to treat the parameter returned data with null or ZERO Records.
If my query does not return any row, I just need to inform data the value null.
I thought that data treated this regardless I passed these columns with each null value will be nicely managed by DataTable.
So I've made a condition an return the properly value.

Comment: Glad i could be of assistance.